# How do I fix this error: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-1,89E-09'"?

Tags: string, python-3.5, scientific-notation

I want to plot numbers in scientific notation by reading and putting these numbers in y-list. Here is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []


with open('test1.txt','r') as csvfile:
     plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')  
        for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))


  plt.plot(x,y, label='20 Volt max with filter')
  plt.xlabel('time')
  plt.ylabel('voltage')
  plt.show()
```

The .txt file looks like this:

```
0   -1,89E-09
0,001   -1,37E-08
0,002   -5,69E-08
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-1,89E-09'
```

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language you're using. Also, you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: im using Spyder (Python 3.5)                                                                                                                        my problem is that im getting                                                         ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-1,89E-09'

Comment: That information needs to be in the question. Add a "python" tag (there may be a separate "python3" tag), and show the exact error message in the question. (I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is, but I'm not going to post an answer yet.)

Comment: thank you for your reply. i have tried to edit to make my problem understandable

Comment: The error message and the question you're asking should be in the body of the question. I've updated it for you.

Comment: And I think your indentation is incorrect. The `for row in plots:` line should have the same indentation as the preceding line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python and many other languages, the standard decimal separator is `.` (period) not `,` (comma).

From [Decimal Mark](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/decimal_mark) on Wikipedia:

> In 1958, disputes between European and American ISO delegates over the correct representation of the decimal mark nearly stalled the development of the ALGOL computer programming language. ALGOL ended up allowing different decimal marks, but most computer languages and standard data formats (e.g. C, Java, Fortran, Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)) specify a dot.

You can change the format used in your text file, or you could `float(row[n].replace(",", "."))`.

Comment: for row in plots: float(row[1].replace(",","."))                                                             x.append(float(row[0]))                                                         y.append(float(row[1]))                                                                                 but i get syntax error what did i do wrong

Comment: You'll need to assign the `float(row[n].replace(",", "."))` to a variable

Comment: `>>> x.append(float(row[0].replace(",", "."))) >>>  y.append(float(row[1].replace(",", ".")))`>>>  _thank you it worked!_

Comment: @kevin I'm glad it worked! You might consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer if it helped :)